# How does `space` paging work in browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine a page with two side-by-side `<div>` elements like https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/.

The `<div>` on the left navigates between pages. The one on the right has the actual content.

When I press `space` (spacebar), the browser advances the content of the right-hand `<div>` by one screenful, reminiscent of the traditional UNIX pager `more`. (IIRC, this has been fairly standard browser behavior since NCSA Mosaic.)

However, sometimes I want to scroll the column on the left (the "navigation" column). How does the browser decide which column to scroll when `space` is pressed? The `document.activeElement` is `<body>`, an ancestor of both of those column `<div>` elements. I want to be able to change the focus using a bookmarklet (or extension)—which I will be happy to write myself, but this mechanism seems not to be governed by `HTMLElement.focus()` in any way that I understand.

Comment: The one on the left in node docs is `position:fixed` which pins it in the viewport so the right is the only part that scrolls with the window through default behavior as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pressing the space bar (or arrow keys, pg-down, pg-up, etc...), the browser scrolls the closest scrollable parent of the currently active element. When you open the page, the active element is `<html>` and that's the element that will be scrolled (if its scrollable) and it the [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) exceeds its height (which, by default, is viewport's `height`).

If the currently active element is the sidebar or one of its children, pressing space will scroll the sidebar, not the `<html>` element. You can change the active element through various methods (clicking, pressing tab, programmatically, etc...).

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand exactly, but I can accomplish what I want. (How does scrolling `<body>` cause its descendant `<div>` to scroll?)

Comment: What do you mean by *"cause its descendant `<div>` to scroll"*? Which `<div>` are you talking about?

Comment: When `document.activeElement` is the `<body>` and I press `space`, the content div (`div#column1`, confusingly, the one on the right) scrolls. If I focus an `<a>` in the navigation div (`div#column2`), then press `space`, then that div scrolls.

Comment: `#column1` is not what's being scrolled. The scrollbar on the right is `<body>`s. `#column1` is just a div inside [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow). In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo6rs.png) the highlighted element is `#column1`. As you can see, the scrollbar exceeds it. As a side note, `#column2` is taken out of normal flow, using `position: fixed`. It has a sidebar because it has a set height and its own flow content exceeds its set height.

Comment: @Colin, actually, I was wrong. The scrolled element is `<html>`, not `<body>`. I'll update the answer. Here's how I tested. I scrolled down and ran: `document.querySelector('#column1').scrollTop // => 0`, `document.querySelector('body').scrollTop // => 0`, `document.querySelector('html').scrollTop // => 900`

Answer (score 2):

use **tabIndex** attribute for manipulate it with focus()

for xmpl with provided by you page:

```
document.getElementById("column2").tabIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("column1").tabIndex = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
    if(event.ctrlKey){
        if(document.activeElement.id=="column1")
            document.getElementById("column2").focus();
        else
            document.getElementById("column1").focus();
    }
});
```